# Rails Routing Questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am very new to Ruby on Rails and I have been working with a project while learning but I have run into an issue. I am trying to set up a link from a view under a "task" controller to a view for new timetracks. I am attempting to link on the view like so:

```
<%= link_to "New Timetrack", new_project_list_task_timetrack_path(@project, @list, @task) %>
```

And I am getting this error:

**No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"timetracks", :project_id=>nil, :list_id=># < List id: 1, name: "Test", description: "Test", created_at: "2013-12-18 21:00:39", updated_at: "2013-12-18 21:00:50", project_id: 1, default: nil>, :task_id=>#>Task id: 1, description: "First Task", completed: false, list_id: 1, created_at: "2013-12-18 21:00:57", updated_at: "2013-12-18 21:00:57", default: nil>}**

I made sure that there was an action "new" in the timetracks controller. I am creating the link the way above because of how I saw Rails scaffold the relation between projects and lists which was like so:

```
<%= link_to "Create To-Do", new_project_list_path(@project) %>
```

So I'm stumped and would like some help. Any information is appreciated!

Comment: I believe you need a route to that relationship in routes.rb then restart the server.

Comment: I think you dont need to pass @project object for new action

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb: no need in development

Comment: rake routes to find the routes?

Comment: When I rake the routes I see the route projects/:project_id/lists/:list_id/tasks/:task_id/timetracks/new

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **new_project_timetrack_path**
If it helpless, look at the output of bash command `rake routes` and find route that you need.

Comment: When I rake the routes I see the route projects/:project_id/lists/:list_id/tasks/:task_id/timetracks/new

Answer (score 0):

in your config/routes.rb must be rows like these:

```
resources :projects do    
  resources :lists do    
    resources :tasks do    
      resources :timetracks    
    end
  end
end
```

and then rake compile path like

```
host:3000/projects/<project_id>/lists/<list_id>/tasks/<task_id>/timetracks/new
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: My routes.rb file does contain this code. Also it is worth noting that the link: new_project_list_task_path(@list) works but new_project_list_task_timetracks_path(@task) does not work

Comment: Task and Timetrack models have relationship ? Timetrack belongs_to Task ? and Project, List have relationship also ?